# Modular design for composer package

Tags: php, module, composer-php

I'm working on a framework-like application, for which I would like people to be able to develop modules.

Modules add additional functionality to the core application by providing information to the core about their capabilities. Examples include modules for allowing access to MySql, or the file system or emails.

While modules can provide as much or as little extra functionality as they like, there is a Module class that is used to wrap the functionality provided, and each module should provide at least one of these classes to be included into the application.

Are there any guides or good practices on methods of module registration in PHP in the composer ecosystem. It would be additionally useful if the modules could provide aliases, and describe any configuration they require.

**Clarification Edit**

I have a core application, we'll call it `example-app`

Anyone using `example-app` should be able to introduce new functionality easily using the modular framework of the app.

So, let's say we have two modules `example-module-1` and `example-module-2`. The app needs to know that these modules exist when it is run from the command line.

Everything should be managed from composer, so you will require the core application, and any modules that you wish to use with it. For example

```
"require" : {
  "php": ">=5.5.0",
  "example/example-app" : "^1.0",
  "example/example-module-1": "^1.0",
  "example/example-module-2": "^1.0"
},
```

What I would like to know is, is there a methodology for the modules to inform the core app at the time of installtion of their existence.

I already have a Module interface that imported modules can sit inside of, I just need a way to make the core app aware of where these classes are defined amongst all the other composer installed dependencies (e.g. I don't want to create a huge class list and step through each one doing `instanceof`).

The only thing I can think to do at the moment is to provide an additional companion app (something like `bin/example-app-config`) that each module calls as part of it's [composer scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#scripts). It could use cli parameters to tell the core app what the module class is called as well as any other requirements it has. However this doesn't sit right with me as it seems like it wouldn't be OS independent.

Comment: do you know about packagist?

Comment: Don't we have that already? It's called Symfony.

Comment: Then what do you mean by composer echosystem? I might got it wrong.

Comment: @Halfstop Symfony Bundles are not the correct way to manage this afaik, as each bundle needs to be managed independently.

Comment: @monir009 So I have my applcation which I want people to require through composer, along with any modules they might need. Eg: `require example-app`, `require example-app-module-1`, `require example-app-module-2`. What I would like is for module-1 and module-2 to register themselves somewhere that the app can see them easily at runtime. It will then dynamicly load the modules next tim it is run. I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: This is actually an inappropriate question for SO as it's not specifically related to a specific programming problem. I've been playing around with the Slim framework, might be a good place to start and then use composer. But I don't really get what you're doing.

Comment: @Halfstop Perhaps I'm explaining it badly, but I don't think you understand. This is not a web app, so Slim and Symfony are not solutions... I don't think they would be even if it was. This is specific to how composer managers packages, and how I can use that to resolve this problem. So although you may not feel it's not specific enough for SO, it is too specific for Programmers.

Comment: You can upload your package/module in the packagist, then all you have to require it by composer. Yes it is possible to set dependency for your module with other modules. Thats what slim, laravel or all the other framework/module does.

Comment: @monir009 That doesn't solve the problem. The app itself needs to know what is available. I don't want to hard code anything.

Comment: @DanielM what do you mean by what is available? Aren't the modules specific or you are talking about version updates?

Comment: The app is able to understand a "description" of work, modules can tell the app what "descriptions" they understand. I can make it so you have to define a list of "descriptions" when the app starts however I want to avoid that. I don't want people to have to touch the codebase just to add more "descriptions", they should be able to just install new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm researching this topic and found your question from long ago.)
It looks like composer now supports enumerating installed packages by type that might help you achieve what you would like. Please see: https://getcomposer.org/doc/07-runtime.md#knowing-which-packages-of-a-given-type-are-installed

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for, thank you!